# Ionic fetch contacts for android

Tags: android, contacts, ionic-framework

i am new to Ionic framework with angular. I need to fetch the phone contacts in my android phone  (ie, mobile number and email),and need to list with a search option. i do googling and find some code , but its not populating the contacts list, is we need to do anything more like adding some plugin.

Whenever I run it, it shows in console "Failed to pick a contact". I'm using [this post](http://calendee.com/2014/07/17/cordova-contacts-plugin-with-ionic-framework/) as reference.

In AndroidManifest I've put the following already:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

Comment: What's the code you tried? Any error thrown when you try to fetch contacts?

Comment: hi thanks for the replay , i follw the blog http://calendee.com/2014/07/17/cordova-contacts-plugin-with-ionic-framework/

Comment: in console it says "Failed to pick a contact".

Answer (score 0):

you need ngCordova module loaded and install, If you use ngCordova module you don't have to add any service to get the contact list, the module already did it for you. Just put this in your controller.

```
module.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaContacts) {
  var contactList = '';
  $scope.addContact = function() {
     $cordovaContacts.save($scope.contactForm).then(function(result) {
     console.log(result);
     contactList = result;
  }, function(err) {
     console.log('err')
  });
  };
```

});

And then use watch.

```
$scope.$watch(function () {
    return contactList;
},
function (newval) {
   var getListContact = newval;
   console.log(getListContact);
   $scope.contactForm = newval;
}, false)
```

Your contact list should be bind to scope contactForm already, if not the watch function will verify 2nd time.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Yes sorry forgot that.

Comment: hi thanks for the replay , i follw the blog http://calendee.com/2014/07/17/cordova-contacts-plugin-with-ionic-framework/   . But i got the blank page alway , not asking for permission ,in android.

Comment: i install cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.contacts from command prompt , still it says 'Failed to pick a contact'.

Comment: post your code here, its easier to understand what is your problem is

Comment: did you add user permission for accessing contact? in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: code from  : http://calendee.com/2014/07/17/cordova-contacts-plugin-with-ionic-framework/ . Yes add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

Comment: @JobiMg Please update your question with the relevant code/config files you are putting here as comments. I got you this time.